# Should sdk = deployment target?

Tags: ios

And what will happen if it's not the case.

This may seem like an easy question.

Say base sdk is 5. Why can't it run on ios 7? What? Ios 7 can't run stuff built with base sdk 5?

So is it true that base sdk must be bigger or equal deployment target? If so why?

What would be the plus and minus if the 2 numbers are different?

I am looking for answers that answer:
1. Bad things happen if sdk > deployment target
2. Bad things happen if deployment target < sdk

Comment: ... It can. I have a build with base 4.2 running on iOS7 right now.

Comment: I updated the question. Would anyone answer please?

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html)

> Choose a **deployment target. This identifies the earliest OS version on which your software can run**. By default, Xcode sets this to the version of the OS corresponding to the base SDK version and later.

And

> Choose a base SDK. **Your software can use features available in OS versions up to and including the one corresponding to the base SDK**. By default , Xcode sets this to the newest OS supported by Xcode.

Your Xcode will likely only have a base SDK option of whichever is the latest iOS version it knows about (6.1 for Xcode 4.5, 7 for Xcode 5). That lets you use the newest features.

> Say base sdk is 5. Why can't it run on ios 7? What? Ios 7 can't run stuff built with base sdk 5?

Nonsense, it can run on iOS7. And it will run on iOS8 when that comes out. It just can't use features that didn't exist yet.

> So is it true that base sdk must be bigger or equal deployment target? If so why?

Xcode let me set base < deployment, but I don't see why you'd want that, or if it would actually run.

> What would be the plus and minus if the 2 numbers are different?

Advantage: you can run your app on older devices.
Disadvantage: you have to make sure that you only call APIs that exist on the current version. Meaning, if you use iOS6-only features, you have to detect that you're running on iOS5 and not use them.